# Bounds for inner product of $Ax$ and $x$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces, inner-products

Reading a math text, I found, with no proof given, the following assertion.

Suppose $A$ is a real $n \times n$ matrix, and suppose the real part of its spectrum lies between $a$ and $b$; i.e., the maximum real part of the eigenvalues of $A$ is $b$, and the minimun real part of the eigenvalues of $A$ is $a$. Then, for every real n-vector $x$ we have

$a ||x||^2 \leq (Ax,x) \leq b||x||^2$ , where $||.||$ is the 2-norm.

Has anyone heard of this? Could you prove it or provide a source where it is proven? Otherwise, could you disprove it?

I find it a little hard to believe, since it would imply, e.g., that in order to see if a non hermitian matrix satisfies $x^t A x > 0 \; \forall x \neq 0$ we can just check if all the eigenvalues of $A$ have positive real part, and I have never heard such a thing (it is said in a variety of sources that for that, one have to look at $A+A^t$ and apply the well known criteria for positive definiteness).

**Edit:**

This doesn't hold if A is not diagonalizable. For example, it isn't true for $A = [-2, 1; 0, -2]$. So, now I ask, can it be shown that it always holds for diagonalizable matrices?

Comment: I don't think this is true, but I'm having a bit of difficulty proving it. My understanding was that the quadratic form corresponding to a non-Hermitian matrix is in general not even bounded below.

Comment: Is it possible that the author intended to only consider diagonalizable matrices (perhaps diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$)? This seems more plausible in that context.

Comment: @Dorebell, it is not stated, but I'm used to some authors making that annoying assumption. Your question is actually very insightful, since it points in the direction of a good counter example. The "theorem" does not hold for $A=[-2, 1; 0, -2] $ . So, I will refrase my question: does it hold for diagonalizable matrices?

Comment: It seems like it shouldn't, because it seems like if you take a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$, hold one eigenvector and both eigenvalues fixed, and then rotate the other eigenvector, then the quadratic form should depend on the angle between the two eigenvectors. Maybe try that; take $A=\frac{1}{\sin(\theta)} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \cos(\theta) \\ 0 & \sin(\theta) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \sin(\theta) & -\cos(\theta) \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ for $\theta \in (0,\pi)$ and see what you get.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that @Ian? Why or how should the quadratic form depend on the angle between the two eigenvectors?

Comment: If $x_1,x_2$ are unit eigenvectors then $(x_1+x_2)^T A (x_1+x_2)=(x_1+x_2)^T (\lambda_1 x_1 + \lambda_2 x_2) = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2) \cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Though I suppose that $\| x_1 + x_2 \|$ is also small when $\cos(\theta)$ is nearly $-1$...hmm...

Comment: it is true if $A$ is normal. Probably also only if. Aside: If you divide by $\|x\|^2$, you obtain the Raleigh quotient. The eigenvalues is contained in the range of Raleigh quotients. There is a bunch theory about eigenvalue approximation by Raleigh quotient.

Comment: Thanks @Ian, but, as you say, $||x_1+x_2 ||$ will also change while varying $\theta$.

Comment: @user251257, if the matrix is hermitian you're totally right. Applying the theorem related to the rayleigh quotient will inmediately prove this. However I'm not so sure about what would happen with a normal non hermitian matrix.. If I recall correctly,  rayleigh quotients are defined only for hermitian matrices.

Comment: In the symmetric case you can exploit orthogonal diagonalizability and everything is simple.

Comment: @LGenzelis I need to correct myself again. A skew symmetric matrix $A$ is no counter example. It's eigenvalues are imaginary, but we have also $(Ax,x) = 0$ for all real $x$.

Comment: also notice that $2(Ax,x) = ((A+A^T) x, x)$ holds for ale real square matrix $A$ and real vector $x$.

Comment: @user251257 in the skew case, the **real** part is zero, so that's fine.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom like I said **no** counter example :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is false, it does not hold disregarding wether the matrix is diagonalizable or not. For a non diagonalizable matrix, take $A=[-2,1;0, -2]$. For a diagonalizable matrix, take $A=[-1,0; 3, -0.2]$.

**Edit:** the textbook I mencioned in the question was incomplete. The correct theorem is that there exist a basis for which this holds. For source, go to *"Differential equations, dynamical systems and linear algebra"* (Hirsch, Smale). It's the lemma at the beginning of chapter 7 (bottom of page 145). Also, the hypotesis should be read as "...suppose the real part of its spectrum lies **strictly** between a and b...".

Comment: why so complicated? a non diagonalizable example $[0, 1; 0, 0]$.

Comment: a diagonalizable counter example $[0, 1 ; 0, 1]$.

Comment: The desired condition is normality